# Convert this string to another with Htaccess code

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, web, url-rewriting

I have this url now :

```
new.php?news&post=111&title=XXXX
```

i want to have this url :

```
new/news/111/XXXX
```

How to do it with Htaccess ?

I tried to convert this with mod_rewrite but i could not !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^/new/news/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /new.php?news&post=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: @Pafo in browser which URL you are giving is it http://localhost/new/news/111/XXXX ??

Comment: TNx, i am testing and fixing my own code, will check ht code soon :X

Comment: Worked, but there is a new problem, if i open `http://localhost/new/news/218/XXX/` it opens , but if i open `http://localhost/fa/news/218/XXX` (without `/` at the end, it doesn't open !) How to solve this one ?

Comment: You are trying to say `http://localhost/new/news/218/XXX/` is working but `http://localhost/new/news/218/XXX` is not working??